# Laurent series of $\ln(1-\frac{2i}{z+i})$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

How to find Laurent series of function $ln\left(1-\frac{2i}{z+i}\right)$ if it is known $1 \leq |z| \leq 2$.

I am confused how to find this, because I tried to prove that $|\frac{2i}{z+i}|<1$ and use formula for $\ln$  series around $0$  but didn't succeed.